# Audio-only ffserver feed / adding dummy video to audio-stream

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, ffserver

I'm trying to stream audio to ffserver, but when I start the ffmpeg client it says:

```
Missing video stream which is required by this ffm
```

Is there a way to either:

- Configure ffserver to allow audio-only streams?
- or add dummy video to the stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lavfi + nullsrc seems to do the trick:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc -i http://remote/stream http://localhost/steam1.ffm
```